# Showing a certain relation for the partial derivatives of two functions

Tags: derivatives, calculus

I'm currently working on a physics exercise where I'm told:

Given two functions $f$ and $g$ which are both continuously differentiable and depend on $x$ and $y$. Show that the following relation holds
$$
 \left(
        \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}
    \right)_g =\left(
        \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}
    \right)_y - \left(
        \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}
    \right)_x \left(
        \frac{\partial g}{\partial x}
    \right)_y \left(
        \frac{\partial g}{\partial y}
    \right)_x^{-1}.
$$

My first approach to this problem was that I build the total derivatives of $f$ and $g$, namely
$$
 d f = \left(
        \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}
        \right)_y d x +
        \left(
            \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}
        \right)_x d y
$$
and
$$
 d g = \left(
        \frac{\partial g}{\partial x}
        \right)_y d x +
        \left(
            \frac{\partial g}{\partial y}
        \right)_x d y.
$$
I then expressed $dy$ as a function of $dg$ and $dx$ and inserted this expression into the $df$ term. Doing this gave me
$$
df = \left[
            \left(
                \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}
            \right)_y - \left(
                \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}
            \right)_x \left(
                \frac{\partial g}{\partial x}
            \right)_y \left(
                \frac{\partial g}{\partial y}
            \right)_x^{-1} 
        \right] d x + \left(
            \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}
        \right)_x \left(
            \frac{\partial g}{\partial y}
        \right)_x^{-1} d g.
$$

The problem is that I don't really know how to go on from here with the information I have available. I think I "could" go on if would make the assumption that I could write
$g=g(x,y) \rightarrow y=y(g,x)$, then build the total derivative of $f(x,y(g,x))$, namely
$$
d f = \left(
            \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}
        \right)_g d x + 
        \left(
            \frac{\partial f}{\partial g}
        \right)_x  \left(
            \frac{\partial g}{\partial y}
        \right)_x d g,
$$
and compare coefficients. But I'm really not sure if I'm allowed to just invert the function $g(x,y)$ with the information I'm handed (that they are continuously differentiable) because, I guess, it's now always possible to invert the function like this?

I would really appreciate any comments on this problem and maybe there is some other approach to this problem which I did not consider.

Comment: The only important point to remember in almost all such derivations is that only a certain number of variables ( 2 above) are independent.  Then what you say is correct; invert anything and assume anything to be a function of two variables.

Comment: You have already arrived at the correct answer using the correct derivation steps. All you are missing is to interpret what you have done.

Comment: I know it is a common notation, especially in thermodynamics, but IMHO it is so confusing. Also, what is the relation between $f$ and $g$?

Comment: Thanks for the comments!
I think the only relation between those two functions is, that they both depend on $x$ and $y$. 
Regarding the intepretation: I guess by expressing $dy$ as function of $dg$ and $dx$, I already wrote down the total derivative of $y=y(g,x)$. This is also the reason why it works out to compare the coefficients of $f(x, y(g,x))$ later on

Answer (score 1):

Your second equation is $$
 d g = \left(
        \frac{\partial g}{\partial x}
        \right)_y d x +
        \left(
            \frac{\partial g}{\partial y}
        \right)_x d y.
$$So, at constant g, $$
 \left(
        \frac{\partial g}{\partial x}
        \right)_y d x +
        \left(
            \frac{\partial g}{\partial y}
        \right)_x d y=0
$$So, $$\left(\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}\right)_g=-\frac{\left(\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}\right)_y}{\left(\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}\right)_x}$$